# How do I upload a certificate to Azure API Management and verify it in your API

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-api-apps, azure-api-management

I want to make my API use a certificate so that API management can talk to the API but no one else can surf directly to the API

I have uploaded a certificate to API Management (APIM) but after that I don't know what to do and the "help" available in blogs is pretty poor.

I have uploaded a self signed certificate to:

Azure | API Management service | Publisher Portal | Security

I have code in the API Controller that interrogates any certificates in the Request but I don't know how the Certificate gets from APIM to the API

What do I do with the uploaded certificate?
I am going down the right path?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates whats wrong with this link?

Comment: I tried that some days ago and couldn't get it to work.
Now after understanding more, yes. that page is the correct one to use and the link to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth